# How omit sheets from the loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to skip copying tables from sheets named "Data" and "Total".

Code below. It goes through all the sheets and adds data to a new sheet called "Together".
However, I want him to omit two specific sheets.

`If Not Sheets(jCt).Name = "Together" Then

For jCt = 2 To Sheets.Count ' From Sheet 2 to the last

How do I do that?
Any help will be welcome

```
  Sub Combination()
Dim jCt As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 1

'Removes the "Together" sheet, if any
If sheetExists("Together") Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Together").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Worksheet ""Together"" deleted!"
End If

Worksheets.Add ' Adds a sheet to the first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Together"

' Sheet processing
For jCt = 2 To Sheets.Count ' From Sheet 2 to the last

    Set myRange = Sheets(jCt).Range(Sheets(jCt).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(jCt).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Debug.Print Sheets(jCt).Name, myRange.Address

    'Copying Sheets
    myRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Together").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow - 1, 0)
    lastRow = lastRow + myRange.Rows.Count + 0 ' Adds the number of rows below the last record

Next

MsgBox "The sheet ""Together"" is created"
End Sub
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Write Worksheet Names to an Array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub arrWorksheetNamesTEST()
    Dim wsNames As Variant: wsNames = Array("Together", "Data", "Total")
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' The Together code...
    
    Dim wsArr As Variant: wsArr = arrWorksheetNames(wb, wsNames)
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(wsArr)
        
    ' The Loop code...
        Debug.Print wb.Worksheets(wsArr(n)).Name
    
    Next n
    
End Sub

Function arrWorksheetNames( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal Exceptions As Variant) _
As Variant
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Dim arr() As String: ReDim arr(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim n As Long
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
                n = n + 1
                arr(n) = ws.Name
            End If
        Next ws
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To n)
        arrWorksheetNames = arr
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

@VBasic2008 , Many thanks for your reply. Finally, I solved the code as follows:

```
Sub Combination2()
Dim jCt As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 1

'Removes the "Together" sheet, if any
If sheetExists("Together") Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Together").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Worksheet ""Together"" deleted!"
End If

Worksheets.Add.Name = "Together"

' Sheet processing
For jCt = 2 To Sheets.Count ' From Sheet 2 to the last
If Sheets(jCt).Name <> "SETUP" Then

    Set myRange = Sheets(jCt).Range(Sheets(jCt).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(jCt).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Debug.Print Sheets(jCt).Name, myRange.Address

    'Copying Sheets
    myRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Together").Range("A1").Offset(lastRow - 1, 0)
    lastRow = lastRow + myRange.Rows.Count + 0 ' Adds the number of rows below the last record

End If
Next
MsgBox "The sheet ""Together"" is created"
End Sub
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```